# worst case comparisons for special case insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Consider an Insertion Sort with a Sentinel on n values, where every value occurs exactly twice in the input (so n must be even). So the best case input for comparisons is when the elements are already sorted and the exact number of comparisons in the best case is n-1. I believe the worst case input for comparisons is when the elements are reverse sorted. But what is the exact number of comparisons in this case? and why?

Comment: Why don't you try some small examples and come up with a plausible hypothesis?

Comment: I believe it is (n+2)(n-1)/2. not sure if correct though.

Answer (score 0):

the array with 1 element is sorted.
and *n*-1 elements inserted to the array

```
for(int i=1 ; i<n ; i++){
   int valueForInsert = a[i];
   .
   .
   .
}
```

for element in index *i*, we have *i* comparisons in worst case.
so 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (*n* - 1) comparisons occurs in reverse sorted array.
and the formula for array with length n is equal to:
(*n* * (*n* - 1)) / 2